# Automatic screen recording when my android phone wakes up

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, automation, macrodroid

I have checked out many Android screen recorders, but none of them start recording the screen automatically when the phone wakes up.
Does anybody know of a screen recorder that does that job?

Comment: Please note that asking for app recommendations is off-topic here. But you might want to check with our [automation tag-wiki](/tags/automation/info) for ideas how to start a certain action (e.g. "launch screen-recorder") at a given event (e.g. "screen on").

Comment: I am sorry Izzy. Didn't Know that. Won't happen again.

Comment: And as I assumed, the answer is "automation" :)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid). This has the same functionality as Automate but is much easier to use. 
To set up this feature:

1. Click "Add Macro"
2. For the trigger, choose Battery/Power. If device is rooted, you can pick the option for when device turns on. Otherwise, you can set another trigger such as "Power button toggle" to do close to the same thing.
3. For actions, you need experimental options enabled (Settings -> experimental features), then select launch and press screen action. You can enable the recording option after this (alternatively, you can set macrodroid to automatically run a recorder by setting the action to launch an app such as [Screen Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kimcy929.screenrecorder)).
4. You can add constraints if you want but as of now it should be able to record once the phone turns on.

Comment: @Ersoy. That looks exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!